# Pandas DataFrameの3次元配列を2次元配列にしたい

Tags: python, pandas

tmp_datというDataFrameは3次元構造となっており、IndexにDate,Codeが指定されており、nm_retという要素が入っています。

イメージとしては、
Date  　　Code　　　　　　nm_ret
日時　　　銘柄コード　　月次リターン
となっています。

ここから、nm_retという行を消し、DateとCodeだけの配列へと変換したいのですが、どのようにすればよいでしょうか。

目標は、
Date    　　Code
日時　　月次リターン
となっていて、Codeは銘柄コードがずらっと並んでいるイメージです。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 例えば、`pd.DataFrame([[d] + [int(x.nm_ret[x.Date == d]) if list(x.Code).index(int(x.Code[x.Date == d])) == i else '' for i in range(len(x.Code))] for d in x.Date], columns=[x.columns[0]] + list(x.Code))` な感じでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんな感じでしょうか？

```
import pandas as pd

# x = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2017/11/5", "2017/11/6"], "Code":[123, 456], "nm_ret": [111, 000]})
# 質問内容で指定されたヘッダーと順番が異なるので書き直しました。
x = pd.DataFrame([["2017/11/5", 123, 111], ["2017/11/6", 456, 000]], columns=["Date", "Code", "nm_ret"])

"""
        Date  Code  nm_ret
0  2017/11/5   123     111
1  2017/11/6   456       0

"""
_x = x.drop("nm_ret", 1)

"""
        Date  Code
0  2017/11/5   123
1  2017/11/6   456
"""
```

**[追記]**
質問者様の質問内容に不明点があったので以下のように理解して上記の回答を書いております。

> tmp_datというDataFrameは3次元構造となっており、IndexにDate,Codeが指定されており、nm_retという要素が入っています。
>
> イメージとしては、
> Date 　　Code　　　　　　nm_ret
> 日時　　　銘柄コード　　月次リターン

質問者様がイメージで表しているものは以下のようなcsvフォーマットであると理解しました。

```
Date,Code,nm_ret
2017/11/5,123,111
2017/11/6,456,0
```

> 目標は、
> Date 　　Code
> 日時　　月次リターン
> となっていて、Codeは銘柄コードがずらっと並んでいるイメージです。
> こういうことでしょうか？

月次リターンの部分は銘柄コードの誤字と理解しました。

**[再追記]**
コメントについてindexの表示がいらないものと判断し以下のコードを再度追記しました。

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame([["2017/11/5", 123, 111], ["2017/11/6", 456, 000]], columns=["Date", "Code", "nm_ret"])

_x = x.drop("nm_ret", 1)
x_to_csv = _x.to_csv(index=False))
print(x_to_csv)

"""
Date,Code
2017/11/5,123
2017/11/6,456
"""
```

Comment: 上の例をお借りさせて頂くと、最終的な目標は、
Date　　123　　456
2017/11/5   111        
2017/11/6              0
というような形にしたいのですが、如何でしょうか。

Comment: 最終的な目標のフォーマットが崩れておりよくわかりません。